# Mysterious limit of a function

Tags: calculus, limits

this is driving me crazy. I need to solve this:

[image]

Here's the riddle: Since it's (0/0), I do L'Hôpital's rule, which means I get to:

[image]

But the limit of this = 0 (after one more use of L'Hôpital's rule). And that is not the correct answer.

HOWEVER, if I just do the derivative of the integral, but LEAVE the denominator as is, then I get this:

[image]

And after some more use of L'Hôpital's rule, this actually comes out to be (-5) - which is supposed to be the correct answer.

So I don't understand why when I use L'Hôpital's rule on the numerator alone - it works, but if I use it on both numerator and denominator (which is how you're supposed to..) - it doesn't.

Would appreciate the solution of this "mystery" :)

Comment: By the way, there is a chance that the "correct" solution given by our teacher is a mistake.. but I didn't want to rely on that unless I get some backup :)

Comment: I'll back you up --- I think 0 is correct.

Comment: I think that $-5$ is correct(using Taylor).

Comment: OK I gather from most replies that indeed the solution given is incorrect. I was confused because with a slight change it was correct (hence the origin of the mistake probably).
Thanks everyone.

Comment: I confess I made a stupid mistake !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this actually comes out to be (-5) - which is supposed to be the correct answer.

It isn't.

If we Taylor-expand the integrand, we get

$$\int_0^x \frac{e^{-5t^2}-1}{t}\,dt = \int_0^x \frac{-5t^2 + O(t^4)}{t}\,dt = \int_0^x -5t + O(t^3)\,dt = -\frac{5}{2}x^2 + O(x^4).$$

The denominator is

$$\sqrt{1+2x}-1 = \left(1+x - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)\right) - 1 = x + O(x^2),$$

so the limit is indeed $0$.

Comment: Great, thanks, I forgot to try using Taylor and compare.

Answer (score 0):

You are right... We have to differentiate both numerator and denominator...your teacher did a silly mistake...

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hospital's Rule, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-5x^2}-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-10xe^{-5x^2}}{1}=0.$ Applying L'Hospital's Rule again, $$\text{the given problem} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\displaystyle \frac{e^{-5x^2}-1}{x}}{(1+2x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}= \frac{0}{1}=0.$$